# jQuery - set input array values from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, input

[image: form output image]

The form have 3 variables: `useredu_id[]` *hidden type*, `useredu_qual[]` *select type*, `useredu_detail[]` *text box*.

I try to set values to using JavaScript array which generated using jQuery ajax and the code is given below. But values are not stored

```
var xx = 0;
var fieldHTML = ''
+ '<div class="form-row field_group">' 
+ $(".field_group_copy").html() 
+ '</div>';
$.each(data.result_qual, function(key, val1) {
    var detail = data.result_detail[key];
    $('input[name="useredu_id[]"]').eq(xx).val(key);
    $('input[name="useredu_qual[]"]').eq(xx).val(val1);
    $('input[name="useredu_detail[]"]').eq(xx).val(detail);
    $('body').find('.field_group:last').after(fieldHTML);
    ++xx;
});
```

Comment: Can you show the ajax response

Comment: Can you setup this on jsfiddle so that we can debug and fix the issue.?

Comment: Your fields are inside of "$(".field_group_copy").html()" this part?

Comment: the mysql record is 
23, some school, 10th
24, Diploma, some diploma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

processData function will handle the response. I have added a test JSON . You can call the function from your ajaz success method. If it is in the given format. Else you need some small changes according to the response

```js
$(function(){
  // let data be your json response from ajax call
  var data = [
    {id:1, qual:"BTECH", detail:"Engineering"},
    {id:2, qual:"MTECH", detail:"Master Engineering"},
    {id:3, qual:"BSC", detail:"Science"},
  ];  
  processData(data);
});

function processData(data){  
  $.each(data, function(index, value) {
    var fieldHTML = ''
      + '<div class="form-row field_group">' 
      + $(".field_group_copy").html() 
      + '</div>';  
    $('body').find('.data-container').append(fieldHTML);
    $('input[name="useredu_id[]"]').eq(index+1).val(value.id);
    $('select[name="useredu_qual[]"]').eq(index+1).val(value.qual);
    $('textarea[name="useredu_detail[]"]').eq(index+1).val(value.detail);    
  });
}
```

```css
.hide{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-row field_group_copy hide">  
  <input name="useredu_id[]" type="hidden">
  <select name="useredu_qual[]">
    <option value="">Select Qualification</option>
    <option value="BTECH">B.Tech</option>
    <option value="MTECH">M.Tech</option>
    <option value="BSC">B.S.C</option>
    <option value="MSC">M.S.C</option>
  </select>
  <textarea name="useredu_detail[]"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="data-container">  
</div>
```

Comment: sorry anish. i accepted the answer. but i dot know what happened. Thank you very much for your help